# How to edit cell of type Linkcolumn in a gridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, hyperlink

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to edit cell of type Linkcolumn in a gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513515/how-to-edit-cell-of-type-linkcolumn-in-a-gridview)

I have a gridview control having 4 columns. one of the column is of type linkcolumn.
user has to enters data for each column.

How can we edit link column cell. if i click on this cell nothing happen.i set its readonly to false also.

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar question to yours, here: [How to edit cell of type Linkcolumn in a gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513515/how-to-edit-cell-of-type-linkcolumn-in-a-gridview), with an accepted answer

Another way would be to inherit from the LinkColumn class your own column type. If you are interested in this approach, I can give you a code sample