# How to edit cell of type Linkcolumn in a gridview

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, hyperlink

I have a gridview control having 4 columns. One of the column is of type `linkcolumn`. The user has to enter data for each column.

How can we edit the link column cell? When I click on this cell nothing happens. I did set its readonly property to false.

Comment: Why are you editing a link column?

Comment: initially all cells are blank user has to enter the text which will turn into an hyper link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your can try creating a textbox control instead and show it when the grid is being edited, this will allow the user to enter the hyperlink's text. Then add code to check if this textbox control has any text and if so you can then display a hypelink control with the value from the textbox and hide the textbox.

Also, my preferred way of doing this is to use grids for viewing only (read only), and then have a separate form with the data entry fields for data entry purposes.

Good luck!